# Basic function in r - error: returning NULL

Tags: r, function

```
my.function <- function(df,col){
    t <- df$col
    return(t)
}
```

This is the code I've written up to subset a column in a dataframe, but it returns NULL, when I attempt this. I don't understand what's wrong. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to use `[[` instead of `$`, otherwise, it will be checking the name of the 'col' as `col` literally instead of the value - i.e. kind of an associative array.  Therefore, when it checks for the column named 'col' and not present, it returns `NULL`

```
iris$col
#NULL
```

So, here, we change the `$` to `[[` and run the `iris` example data

```
my.function <- function(df, col){
   t <- df[[col]]
    return(t)
   }

my.function(iris, "Species")
my.function(iris, 5)
```